# Given $H<G$, show that $K=\{x\in G:xax^{-1}\in H \iff a\in H \}$ is a subgroup of $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

I tried to prove the following problem:

> Given $H<G$, show that $K=\{x\in G:xax^{-1}\in H \iff a\in H \}$ is a subgroup of $G$.

I have written it in a (perhaps) very detailed way to make it clear to me. We want to show the following items:

---

$$x,y \in K \implies xy \in K$$

For this, I wrote the following:

1. If $x \in K$ then $a\in H \implies xax^{-1} \in H$.
2. If $x \in K$ then $xax^{-1} \in H \implies  a\in H$.
3. If $y \in K$ then $a\in H \implies yay^{-1} \in H$.
4. If $y \in K$ then $yay^{-1} \in H \implies  a\in H$.

We want to show that:

- If $xy\in K$ then $xya(xy)^{-1}\implies a\in H$
- If $xy\in K$ then $a\in H \implies xya(xy)^{-1}$

For the first bullet, we get:

$yay^{-1} \in H \stackrel{1}{\implies}x(yay^{-1})x^{-1}=xya(xy)^{-1}\in H$

For the second bullet, we get:

$x(yay^{-1})x^{-1} \in H \stackrel{2}{\implies} yay^{-1} \in H \stackrel{4}{\implies} a\in H$

A similar argument is valid exchanging $x$ and $y$.

---

$$x\in K \implies x^{-1} \in K$$

For this, I wrote the following:

1. If $x\in K$ then $a\in H \implies xax^{-1} \in H$.
2. If $x \in K$ then $xax^{-1} \in H \implies  a\in H$.

We want to show that:

- If $x^{-1} \in K$ then $x^{-1}ax \in H\implies a\in H$.
- If $x^{-1} \in K$ then $a\in H\implies x^{-1}ax \in H$.

For this, I needed to prove that the identity $(e)$ is in $K$ which is simple and I'll not transcribe it here.  For the first bullet, I wrote:

$x^{-1}ax\in H \stackrel{1}{\implies} H \ni x(x^{-1}a x)x^{-1}=a$

For the second bullet, I wrote:

$H \ni a=eae^{-1}=x(x^{-1} a x)x^{-1}  \stackrel{2}{\implies} x^{-1}ax \in H$

---

Is it correct?

Comment: Note that your definition is that $xax^{-1}\in H\iff a\in H$; you are only using and only establishing the $\Leftarrow$ direction, so that is a potential source of concern, no?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I'm using both, no? Each bullet is one proposition that must be proved and below them, there is a proof for each one of them (I guess, unless you're talking about something I didn't notice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct!

I would just change the writing a bit: Instead of writting “If $\square \in K$ then $\ldots$” in each bullet, write simply the “$\ldots$” part. You want to show that $xy \in K$ and that $x^{-1} \in K$, not an implication of the form “If … then …”.

I hope I have made clear the above part. :)

Here is another way:
Note that
$$\begin{align*}
K &= \{x \in G : \forall a \in G \ (xax^{-1} \in H \iff a \in H)\} \\
&= \{x \in G : \forall a \in G \ (a \in x^{-1}Hx \iff a \in H)\} \\
&= \{x \in G : x^{-1}Hx=H\}
\end{align*}$$
and from here is pretty straighforward prove that $K$ is a subgroup of $G$. Notice that the fact $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ is not used anywhere, so $K$ is still a subgroup of $G$ if $H$ is just a subset of $G$.

We have a special name for this subgroup, the [*normalizer of $H$ in $G$*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centralizer_and_normalizer#Definitions), and is denoted by $N_G(H)$.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that the "if $\square\in K$" confused a little bit.